# To check the matrix is invetible

Tags: linear-algebra

I am trying to solve the problem that is given below but I couldn't.

Suppose $A$ is $n\times n$ invertible matrix and $B$ is an $n\times n$ matrix such that $$\| A-B\| \leq \frac{1}{\| A^{-1}\|}.$$ Is $B$ invertible matrix.

Comment: What if $B=0$ and $A$ is the identity?

Comment: If the inequality is strict $<$, then $AB=I-(I-AB)$ has inverse $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(I-AB)^n$, which converges because $\|I-AB\|<1$.

Answer (score 3):

$B$ could be invertible: simply take $B=A$.

But it could also not be: take $B=0$ and $A=I_n$.